# Cannot re-add cache device to zpool

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux, zfs-l2arc

I have a cache device that fell out of the zfs array because of errors.  Im pretty sure it was something i did - messing with cabling or something.  It checks out fine, plus its just a cache device.  When i try to readd it, it fails with the following error:

```
# zpool add array cache /dev/sdj2
cannot add to 'array': one or more vdevs refer to the same device
```

is there a way to remove the reference from the zpool array so i can readd it?  ive tried remove:

```
# zpool remove array /dev/sdj2
cannot remove /dev/sdj2: no such device in pool
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed to remove/recreate the zfs partition on the disk itself.  after that, i was able to readd it.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting your pool and re-importing it via `path` or `id` labels. Then you should be able to remove / add your cache device.

For example:

- `zpool export array`
- `zpool import array -d /dev/disk/by-path/`
- `zpool remove array <dev>` as needed.

Comment: tried with both `/dev/sdj2` and `pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-2-part2`, removing results in the same error, as does adding